# How to keep one column constant while adding a list as the second column in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a dataframe with a constant as the first column and the second column being values from a list.

eg.

```
col1    | col2
:-----: |:-----:
A       |  12
A       |  31
A       |  23
A       |  57
```

here the col2 values are coming from a list.

My code is :

```
newList = [12,31,23,57]
for value in newList:
        newerList.append('A', value)
```

This throws an error: 'TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object'

Answer (score 0):

Try `newerList['col1']='A'`

```
import pandas as pd

newerList = pd.DataFrame(
    [12, 31 ,23, 57], columns=['col2']
)
newerList['col1'] = 'A'

print(newerList)
#    col2 col1
# 0    12    A
# 1    31    A
# 2    23    A
# 3    57    A
```

Comment: thanks Terry. But this doesnt print it as your output. it prints the columns separately with separate indexes for both.
i.e.
#    col2 
# 0    12    
# 1    31    
# 2    23    
# 3    57

#     col1
# 0    A
# 1    A
# 2    A
# 3    A

Comment: Also I have put this in another loop so the col1 values do change, hence the append.